# Como montar uma matriz com std::array e std::vector em C++11?

Tags: array-multidimensional, c++11

Como montar uma matriz com std::array e std::vector em C++11 ? Qual a diferença entre as duas arquiteturas? Como varrer esta matriz com C++11?

Answer (score 1):

**Matriz com std::vector**

Para criar uma matriz com `std::vector` temos de fazer um `std::vector` dentro de outro, e para percorrer podemos usar o `for :` que o c++11 fornece:

```
//matrix de 2 x 2 com std::vector 
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matriz = { {7, 5}, {16, 8}};

for(std::vector<int> linha: matriz) { //percorrer cada linha
    for (int linha : vetor){ //percorrer cada numero dentro da linha
        std::cout << numero << ' '; 
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

**Matriz com std::array**

Se for com `std::array` a inicialização já fica um pouco diferente, assim como o próprio `for`, apesar de ser o mesmo principio:

```
//matrix de 3 x 2 com std::array 
std::array<std::array<int, 3> , 2> matriz2 = {{ {{2 , 5, 3}} , {{1, 4, 8}} }};

for (auto& linha : matriz2){
    for (auto& numero : linha){
        std::cout << numero << ' ';
    }

    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

[Exemplo para testar no ideone](http://ideone.com/4oHt5Q)

**Diferenças**

A maior diferença entre as duas é que `std::array` é um array de tamanho fixo e que corresponde a fazer algo como `array[10]`, que não pode mudar, ao passo que `std::vector` pode receber mais elementos dinamicamente utilizando a função `push_back`, assim:

```
std::vector<int> v = {7, 5, 16, 8};
v.push_back(15); //adiciona outro elemento a este vetor
```

Ou remover utilizando a função `pop_back`:

```
v.pop_back(); //remove o ultimo 15 adicionado
```